# Determine actual blocking time of GC compact

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I've heard that a GC run doesn't completely block your application, only, when it needs to perform heap compaction. Is there any way to determine the amount of time a .NET application is actually blocked by the GC performing compaction? Doesn't look like there is such a performance counter...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `% Time in GC` counter. It's updated after every garbage collection. A value of 30% means that, between the end of the previous garbage collection and the current one, your application had 70% of the cpu cycles, and GC took 30%, of your process total cpu-cycles.

Source: [GC Performance Counters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx)

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not what I'm looking for. The "% Time in GC" shows how much of the CPU time the GC has been active, however, not how much it completely blocked the application (as I said, new GC implementations block the application only during the compaction phase).